# CSS attribute selector, multiple classes, wildcards applied to one class definition possible?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Consider the following markup with 2 possibilities:

```
<input class="someclass ng-valid ng-invalid-otherstuff ng-valid-amountdetermined   some-other-class">
<input class="someclass ng-invalid ng-valid-otherstuff ng-invalid-amountdetermined some-other-class">
```

"Amount" is a variable word, this could be anything, "message", "account", anything really. I need to be able to make the distinction in CSS. The attribute selector fails short as it considers the entire attribute value for ^, *, | or even ~.

I would need to single out a class, then check if that class is "ng-valid-*determined". It appears to me this is simply not possible using css, or am I missing something?

A workaround would be to generate "ng-valid-determined*" but this is exactly what I would like to avoid. Does anyone have any ideas on this? As a clarification, I do not know what the ''someclasses' are, I cannot use them for pinpointing my css selector. The problem is exactly that the class I need could be located anywhere inside the class array.

I created a fiddle to visualise the problem, this is of course not the solution as I need to be able to target ng-valid-*determined or ng-invalid-*determined

http://jsfiddle.net/mC2EW/

Not to be confused with [using two css attribute selectors with *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180757/using-two-css-attribute-selectors-with)

//edit1: simplified the question
//edit2: added a fiddle

Comment: Is there a reason you're storing whatever the `ng-x-VALUEdetermined` is in a class and not in a `data` attribute?

Comment: `ng` implies to me you're using Angular. Can't you just use an ngClass directive to add a specific class under the conditions you need?

Comment: @keithjgrant exactly. But I would like *not* to write my own directive for that. Angular generates these classes automatically and I would like to hook into these classes to style my input boxes.

Comment: You shouldn't need yout own directive. Read up on the ngClass one. Shouldn't be much harm in adding one more class to the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, this is not doable with selectors alone given your current situation. Attribute selectors don't have a way of using wildcards in the middle of a value nor can they allow checking of individual components in a space-separated attribute, nor do class selectors provide such functionality. You could consider this a design flaw of AngularJS or one of CSS, but whatever it is, it's not doable with a pure CSS selector.

You will **have** to work around this a different way. As mentioned in the comments, you can easily hook on to `ng-class` to add custom classes to make selecting easier, or as suggested in another answer, consider using data attributes to store validation information instead.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid it wasn't possible but at least I have a confirmation now :). I will look into the other answers to create a workaround. I marked this as the answer as it explains the (im)possibility of my request.

Answer (score 5):

Even though this is an old one, I was looking for a similar solution. I believe I have the best answer, please see my [pen](http://codepen.io/mofeenster/pen/jPqXRq).

**HTML**

```
<input class="someclass ng-valid ng-invalid-otherstuff
ng-valid-amountdetermined some-other-class"> <input class="someclass
ng-invalid ng-valid-otherstuff ng-invalid-amountdetermined
some-other-class">
```

**CSS**

```
[class*=ng-valid][class*=ng-invalid-otherstuff][class*=determined] {
background: #000; }
[class*=ng-invalid][class*=ng-valid-otherstuff][class*=determined] {
background: #ddd; }
```

It turns out that while you cannot target multiple wildcards within the same attribute selector, you can chain wildcard attribute selectors to find your target.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you can't simply use `[class*="amount"]`?

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/z4x5Z/).

It sounds like you're using classes to hold what would be better suited in a `data-*` attribute.

```
<input class="someClass determined" data-validity="valid" data-amount-determined="false" />
<input class="someClass determined" data-validity="invalid" data-amount-determined="true" />
```

[JSFiddle example using `data`](http://jsfiddle.net/z4x5Z/2/).

Comment: I believe that he/she is trying to specifically target `ng-(.*)determined` regardless of the valid/invalid/random field contained.

Comment: I've modified my answer. I think he/she is attempting to store data as a class name. `data` would be more appropriate here I think.

Comment: Maybe I should've clarified, I'm using angular flags for my validity (using directives). Angular generates the "ng-invalid-amountdetermined" class. I'll need to look into the data tags, but the logic described in the question is what angular generates automatically. I would like to hook in on that and not write my own. Sorry for not making that clear from the get-go.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best that you could do here is look for the .someclass and then check if it also has *determined* as well:

```
input.someclass[class*="determined"] { background-color: red; }
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gaE5X/

Comment: Hmmmm, I don't know what the someclasses are, and I can't use them in my css selectors. I will update my question to reflect this. The problem is also that the line above will select all my input fields. I need to be able to make a distinction. I will add a jsFiddle for that.